# how to draw a square with oval side using canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm trying to make the bottom side semicircular, but it doesn't work.
An example of a figure in "main background"

[main background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUR2H.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Path object by issuing 4 individual draw commands (3 draw lines for the 3 straight sides, 1 drawArc for the bottom), then draw that path to the canvas